# Rails how to change view dependent on instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this domain search action:

```
def domain
country_codes = ['.dk', '.com', '.eu', '.net', '.org', '.biz', '.info', '.nu', '.name', '.se', '.fi', '.net', '.de', '.it'] # etc. could move this to a config if needed
@domain = params[:domain]
@results = {}
country_codes.each do |cc|
  @results[cc] = Whois.whois(@domain + cc)
end
  render :layout => false
end
```

If the `params[:domain]` are "asdasdasd" or "something" I want to render the default view.

But if the `params[:domain]` are example "asdasd.dk" or "asdasdasd.com" I want to render the this action and send the domain params to this action:

```
def domainname
@tld = "get the tld" 
country_codes = [@tld]
@results = Domains.order("#{@tld} ASC")
country_codes.each do |cc|
  @results[cc] = Whois.whois(@domain + cc)
end
  render :layout => false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The params are available in both actions, you don't need to "send" them to the second method; they're already there.

Just call the second method if your conditions are met, otherwise do what you're already doing.

Comment: How do I check that the params[:domain] have a TLD?

Comment: Check out the [Array docs on apidoc](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array); there are a bunch of ways to do it. Note there are [additional TLDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) compared to your list; that may or may not be important.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to write a before_filter, but after a thought, making it a one action will be more DRY...

```
def domain
  codes = get_tld(params[:domain]) || country_codes
  codes.each do |c|
    @results[c] = Whois.whois(@domain + c)
  end
    render :layout => false
  end
end

# return array with one element if matched, else nil
def get_tld(string)
  country_codes.each{|cc| return [cc] if string.end_with?(cc)}
  nil
end

#contry_codes should be defined somewhere else...
```

I don't understand what @results = Domains.order("#{@tld} ASC") is supposed to do, but if you need to do something with results in case you have tld in params, you can always check codes.size==1